# Get numpy array from an array of tuples

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tuples, mysql-python

I was using numpy, MySQLbb and scipy and ended up with an array of tuples from a MySQL cursor execution. Then I used np.fromiter. Now I have an array of tuples that looks like this:

```
>>> A
array([('bob', 0.43), ('dan', 0.24), ('bill', 0.14)
       ('sharen', 0.28), ..., ('zena', 0.24), ('zoe', 0.39)],
      dtype = [('f0', 'S10'), ('f1', '<f4')])
```

How do I make a numpy array for the first part of each tuple? I tried:

```
>>> Names = A[:][0]
```

I also tried:

```
>>> Names = np.array(A[:][0])
```

But that didn't work; only gave me the first tuple. I couldn't find any documentation for that specific example.

I want an numpy array like this:

```
>>> Names 
array[('bob', 'bill', all the other names...
>>> Numbers
array[(0.43, 0.24, etc...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that really the output, with a missing `,` and a missing `]`?

Comment: In the future, just copy and paste your code and output. That way we can see exactly what you have—and, better yet, we can usually copy and paste it into an interpreter session or script and _test_ it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you got there is a [`recarray`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html).

The first field in your array is named 'f0'. You can tell that from the `dtype` part (`A.dtype`).

You access it as `A['f0']` or `A.f0`.

```
Names = A.f0
Numbers = A.f1
```